# Invalid crendetials when runing composer require magento 2 extension

Tags: magento2, composer

I got this error when running this command composer require my extension from marketplace :[image]

Comment: have you added credentials in  auth.json.sample or auth.json ?

Comment: yes , but no result same error

Comment: can you please answer me this question and i will be thankfull pleaase https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243229/the-menu-tarck-order-not-shown-in-top-menu