# the menu Tarck order not shown in top menu

Tags: magento2, shipment-tracking

I installed this extension `Evincemage_Trackorder` magento 2 on new project with no other menu it works fine and it appears.

but when i installed it on my project that contain many menu so it does not appear please can any one help me figure out the pb and thanks in advance